# Screen corruption after suspend

Tags: display, suspend

not really sure what to call this, but if my computer wakes up from sleep, I have no issues, however if my computer resumes from a suspend action, then my screen looks like the attached screenshot.

I have an Nvidia Graphics card with the Nvidia 390 driver installed

[image: Screenshot of resume state]

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you just use Intel graphics (disable nvidia)?

Comment: Hmm to be honest I have never tried that as I pretty much depend on the Nvidia driver, but will test it quick and post back

Comment: I gave it a try and removed the nvidia driver, rebooted and entered suspend mode. When I tried to resume I get the blank window with flashing cursor, that wont accept any inputs at all. I could not even log in using control + Alt + f1.. So for now Ill rather have the display graphics corruption - lol

Comment: I was battling this issue on an older GeForce G210 but only with the proprietary drivers. With Xorg drivers, I had no issues but no performance either :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the same issue on Dell XPS 15 even with much newer Nvidia Driver, as workaround switched to Inter Graphic card. Only on Inter Suspend and Resume work good. Waiting for nvidia bug fix.

Comment: Seems this is still an issue with Odin and Nvidia